# What's the max level cap?

Tags: destiny

Is there a level cap, if anything, in Destiny?

From this [article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-08-01-destiny-has-a-soft-level-cap-of-20-but-you-can-go-beyond-it), it says there's a soft level cap of 20, but it says you can go past that.

Does this mean the level cap is stuck at 20, but then how does it say you can go past that?

Comment: With house of Wolves out now the new level cap is 34. You can use etheric light to ascend (upgrade) any of your old legendary or exotics though to catch up with the new gear and level cap. Get more info here: http://goo.gl/VPztvk

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The soft level capacity is at 20, yes. That means when you reach level 20, experience will no longer make you level any more. If you want to go past level 20, you'll need [Motes of Light](http://www.destinypedia.com/Mote_of_Light) to buy equipment from the Speaker. This armor will have a stat called [Light](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Light) which determines how many more levels past 20 you can get to. Max level 32. This increases when new content is added to Destiny.

**EDIT:**
The class items bought from the Speaker does **not** give any stats. So the only way to get equipment with the Light stat is to kill enemies and hope for good equipment with the light stat. Only higher level equipment will have the light stat.

**EDIT 2 (Feb 6, 2015)**
Motes of Light are given to you when you accumulate experience after you've reached level 20.   Equipment with the Light stat can be bought from the [Vanguards](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Vanguard) and from [Xûr](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/X%C3%BBr). It can also be awarded after missions, strikes, raids, and battles in the [Crucible](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Crucible)/[Iron Banner](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Iron_Banner). The rarer the equipment, the more light.

**UPDATE: (May 19, 2015)**
With house of Wolves out now the new level cap is 34. You can use etheric light to ascend (upgrade) any of your old legendary or exotics though to catch up with the new gear and level cap. Get more info here: http://goo.gl/VPztvk

**Update: (September 9, 2015)**

With [Update 2.0.0](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/News?aid=13474) the Character Level Cap will be increased to 40 on 9/15/15, and you no longer need armors' light stat to further increase your effective level. It's now purely EXP based.  There is also now a gear score component, where each equippable gear piece's defense or a attack level contributes to your overall light level.  This maxes out at 310, and is based on the average value (possibly with some weighting) of all of your currently equipped gear.

**Update: (April 12, 2016)**

Bungie released their [Update 2.2.0](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/44609) on April 12th, 2016. The Light Level was increased to 335; the maximum XP level still caps at 40

**Update: (September 20th, 2016)**

In the [Rise of Iron](https://www.bungie.net/en/News/Article/45265/7_Destiny-Rise-of-Iron) Expansion, Bungie increased the maximum light to 385

Comment: The equipment at the speaker bought with motes of light are class armor that do **NOT** add light stats.  To improve your light level you'll need to find gear with light or grind faction rep/marks to purchase gear with light from faction vendors in the tower.

Comment: @turbo I'm sorry if I'm mistaken here, I only wrote what I'd been able to find on the internet. I have not played the game enough yet to see this for myself. Digging deeper, I found what you said true, and I will add an edit to my original answer so this it does not mislead anyone! :)

Comment: To further clarify you can buy equipment with light on it, just not from the speaker. The vanguard class vendor sells armour with light on once your rep is high enough and I am pretty sure (though I've not looked as closely) that other faction vendors do likewise.

Comment: Probably should update this stating that with expansions the max level due to light can and probably will change (i.e. with Crota's End the max cap is now 32).

Comment: Armour can be purchased from both the Vanguard and the Crucible vendors at Rank 3 reputation using marks and the respective commendations

Comment: You should also update your beginning note to reflect that the armor's light value no longer matters and it's purely EXP 1-40 now.

Answer (score -10):

I don't have source but I believe it's 50 and that's when you're officially Legendary and have every legendary piece of armour.

Answer (score -10):

IGN has already [released an article of someone](http://www.ign.com/articles/2014/09/09/destiny-already-has-max-level-players-wandering-around) being level 26 and saying that's max level.

Comment: Do you have a link for this, or an official source?